# Adding a .click function to an array of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

Hi I have the following code. I would like to update my Google Maps Marker with the location given from a clicked image. Currently i have an array of images being created inside the for loop. When a user clicks on an image i would like the restMarker to update with the new longitude and latitude. Then the marker position is updated outside the loop. I can not seem to get the code below to work.

```js
var restMarker = {
  lat: 0, //Just set to a trivial value 
  lng: 0
};

let imagesZom = $("#zomato");
for (i = 0; i < passArrayI.length; i++) {
  imagesZom.append(
    $("<a>").attr("href", passArrayW[i])
      .attr("target", "_blank")
      .append("<img id = img" + i + " " + "src =" + passArrayI[i] + "</img>")
      .click(function() {
        restMarker = {
          lat: parseFloat(passArrayLat[i]),
          lng: parseFloat(passArrayLong[i])
        };
      })
  )
}

setTimeout(function() {
  marker.setPosition(restMarker);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}, 100)
```

When i run the following code it works but when i try to put it into a for loop like above i can't get it to work.

```
var restMarker = {
  lat: parseFloat(passArrayLat[0]),
  lng: parseFloat(passArrayLong[0])
};
setTimeout(function() {
  marker.setPosition(restMarker);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}, 100)
```

Comment: The issue is caused by variable scope. `let i = 0` in the loop should fix this problem. Possible duplicate of [JS loop variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999502/js-loop-variable-scope)

Comment: This didn't fix the problem

Comment: you dont close an img with `</img>`, just `/>`

Answer (score 0):

in loop you are overriding same `restMarker` variable inside click event handler. 
you can push longitude and latitude in data attributes of image and retrive it while calling click event handler. see below code

```
    var restMarker = {
      lat: 0, //Just set to a trivial value 
      lng: 0
    };

    let imagesZom = $("#zomato");
    for (i = 0; i < passArrayI.length; i++) {
      imagesZom.append(
        $("<a>").attr("href", passArrayW[i])
          .attr("target", "_blank")
          .append("<img class='mapImage' id ='img" + i + "' src ='" + passArrayI[i] 
               + "' data-lat='" + passArrayLat[i] 
               + "'  data-long='" + passArrayLong[i] + "'> </img>");
        );
    }

    // write separeate click handler for all images
   $(document).on('click','.mapIamge',function() {
            var latVal = $(this).data('lat');
            var lngVal = $(this).data('long');
            restMarker = {
              lat: parseFloat(latVal),
              lng: parseFloat(lngVal)
            };
   });

    setTimeout(function() {
      marker.setPosition(restMarker);
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
    }, 100);
```